# Split on new line when using BufferedReader Android

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader

I am trying to read from a text file, splitting the contents when a new line character is met and displaying the result in a TextView.

This is the readfromfile method that I have:

```
public String readFromFile(Context context) {
        String ret = "";
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = context.openFileInput("history.txt");
            if ( inputStream != null ) {
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                String receiveString = "";
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                    //receiveString.split("\n");
                    //String[] split = receiveString.split("\n\\s*");
                    stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
                   // if((receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) == "\n"){
                   // }
                }
                inputStream.close();
                //stringBuilder.
                ret = stringBuilder.toString();
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("login activity", "File not found: " + e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, "You have not sent any messages!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("login activity", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cannot read from file!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

And this is where the method is called:

```
String message = readFromFile(getApplicationContext()); // is this really needed? yes it is, use with readFromFile()
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, history.getId()); // this is very important for spacing using ids
        textView.setTextSize(14); //this might give an error or look weird on devices, horizontally and vertically
        textView.setText(message); // simplest fix is to force device to stick with horizontal, no common device is bigger than 5.5"
        //textView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        textView.setId(View.generateViewId()); // This requires a minimum API 17
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.BOTTOM);
        layout.addView(textView, params2);
```

I think the issue might be the `append` that I am using with the string to display, i.e. I am returning a string with appended text.

This is the View output:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPFcG.png)

I am trying to load from a file called *history.txt*, which contains all SMS's that have been sent using the app in string format.

This is the writeToFile method:

```
public void writeToFile(String data,Context context) {
        try {
            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(context.openFileOutput("history.txt", Context.MODE_APPEND));
            //format data string here to include time stamp
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);

            String currentDateTime = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());

                outputStreamWriter.append("\n");
                outputStreamWriter.append(data);
                outputStreamWriter.append(" ");
                outputStreamWriter.append(currentDateTime);
                writer.newLine();

                outputStreamWriter.close();

        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What problem do you have? Something goes wrong?

Comment: @greenapps Yeah sorry, edited the above with the output on screen. It is displaying a chunk of text instead of a separated entries, that would be the desired output

Comment: You should of course first tell us which texr you try to load as that output tells us nothing. How should we know how it should look like?

Comment: @greenapps I am trying to load all text that is contained in the _italic_ history.txt_italic_  file. I have also added the writeToFile code in the post above. So what I want is to load and split on new line, each SMS, each entry starting from "Customer".

Comment: You should not show the code to write that text file but the text file itself.

Comment: `to load and split on new line`. The wording of you is strange. You have a text file. That text file contains lines. Now you are reading the file line by line with `readLine()`. And each line you add to a string builder. Now tell what goes wrong with the added lines? Do you really add those lines to the stringbuilder again?

Comment: The input is already split at newlines, by `readLine()`. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: What I'm asking is, how can I output on screen the contents of the text file, seperately and neatly under each other? Right now it grabs everything from file, disregarding the new lines, and outputting a chunk of text. What you see in the output image needs to be two sentences for example, starting from the word "Customer"

Comment: No, that's not what you're asking. You're asking how to split a text file at the newlines. It's up there in black and white. If that's not what you're asking, you should edit your title and your question so it does state what you're asking.

Comment: Perhaps you should be using a ListView instead.

Comment: Since you want to display the entire contents of the file, why don't you just read the entire thing and slap it into the TextView in one fell swoop? I don't see any reason for a loop especially since it seems to eat your newline characters anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you should use a ListView instead. Each row of the ListView can be a single TextView for a single line from the file or can be multiple TextViews if you want to break the data into nicely formatted columns.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Javadoc. `readLine()` removes the line terminator. If you want lines when you do the output, you have to add line terminators yourself: in this case by adding `\n` or `\r\n` to every like as you read it, as you're displaying the data in a GUI.

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved by adding and if condition. Since the amount of variables is set and will not be changed, on every 8 read lines, two lines are skipped like so:

```
 while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                    //receiveString.split("\n");
                    //String[] split = receiveString.split("\n\\s*");
                    stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
                    if(i == 8) {
                        stringBuilder.append("\n");
                        i = 0;
                    }
                    stringBuilder.append("\n");
                   // if((receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) == "\n"){
                   i++;
                   // }
                }
```

Thankyou all for your input!

p.s As @Code-Apprentice pointed out, ListView should have been the way to go from the start.